# How do I make a property grid show certain values as readonly? C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, readonly, propertygrid

There are properties that I want to not be editable via the property grid, but I still want them to be visible, even expandable.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use   `[ReadOnly(true)]` attribute on properties which you want to make read only like this

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public int ReadOnlyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _ReadOnlyProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _ReadOnlyProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, by default property is not read only . It will only be read only if you apply read only attribute on it

Comment: @Haris Hasan: he meant that he wanted to know if it would make the setter not accessible to any code.